# Font-awesome not properly displaying on Firefox / how to vend via CDN?

Tags: css, firefox, cross-domain, font-awesome

I can't get font-awesome to display properly in firefox, even in localhost. I'm receiving the following cross domain error:

```
Timestamp: 08/08/2012 02:49:37 PM
Error: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal     `src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://localhost:3000/djpsite/baseadmin/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
Source File: http://localhost:3000/djpsite/baseadmin/css/font-awesome.css
Line: 0
Source Code:
@font-face {   font-family: "FontAwesome";   font-style: normal;   font-weight: normal;   src: url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome") format("svg"); }
```

I used double quotes as suggested by this post: [firefox @font-face fail with fontawesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072655/firefox-font-face-fail-with-fontawesome) but that didn't resolve the problem.

Everything works fine in Chrome; any suggestions?

Beyond fixing the problem in Chrome, how should I vend font-awesome over a CDN given this restriction: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-fonts/#default-same-origin-restriction?

Below is the code from my CSS file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot");
    src: url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
    url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff") format('woff'),
    url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'),
    url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome") format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This should solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867920/safe-to-allow-webfonts-to-be-loaded-from-subdomains-in-apache

Comment: As an aside, I've found I like using http://icomoon.io/ even more than font-awesome. More precision, smaller files.

Comment: For anybody else stumbling here, the link by JoeyP above has been removed. The answer by styu below works if your FF error console shows "Downloadable font download failed" due to cross origin issues and you are running an Apache webserver.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[This](http://www.red-team-design.com/firefox-doesnt-allow-cross-domain-fonts-by-default) solved the Firefox cross domain font issue for me (which causes the font to not load in Firefox). Just add the following to `.htaccess` or directly to apache config:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

There is a webpage with instructions on how to set up CORS with different servers:
https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: You may need to "sudo a2enmod headers" and restart Apache before this works.

Comment: When I add this to my httpd.conf, the Apache will not restart afterwards. Can this break the config somehow?

Comment: @ArtforLife do you see any error message in the log?

Comment: "Just add the following to .htaccess" - In which directory?

Comment: Thanks so much. This is a lifesaver.

Answer (score 3):

I've usually found adding a local declaration fixes this, as per [this](http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/).
e.g.:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Your typeface";
  src: url("type/filename.eot");
  src: local("☺"),
    url("type/filename.woff") format("woff"),
    url("type/filename.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("type/filename.svg#filename") format("svg");
}
```

I'm sure the Apache config method is more correct, however you may not be using Apache or may not have the ability to make such overrides.

Answer (score 2):

If you're building a rails app (or some other rack based app) take a look at https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors Super easy to get up and running. You can throw it into `application.rb` or one of the environment files.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using AWS Cloudfront as in my case, you'll need to [add a CORS Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html). S3 intentionally won't allow you to set the headers during upload because you need to use the policy instead.

This policy configuration should do the trick for you:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

This will get Font-Awesome working from a CDS on Firefox and Internet Explorer (IE).

Comment: Doesn't this then also open the floodgates for hotlinking? Having a similar issues for  DigitalOcean Spaces Bucket where images and the webfonts are at. Still learning about CORS but allowed origins ** (all) sounds risky to me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on magento 2.0. It was working fine on https but not on http. In order to allow font-awesome icons to load on http. I added following in the .htaccess situated on root directory of magento installation.

```
<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|woff)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```