# GWT Font-awesome not properly displaying on Firefox

Tags: google-app-engine, firefox, cross-domain, font-awesome

I can't get font-awesome to display properly in firefox, even in localhost. I'm receiving a cross domain error, exactly what's reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872404/font-awesome-not-properly-displaying-on-firefox-how-to-vend-via-cdn).

The solution to this problem is to add the following to .htaccess or directly to apache config:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

But I'm hosting my app in Google App Engine, so how can y set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Java, edit your `appengine-web.xml` file to include something like

```
<static-files>
  <include path="/my_static-files" >
    <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </include>
</static-files>
```

Or to avoid potential security issues from using `value=*` as noted by @mabn.

```
<static-files>
  <include path="/my_static-files" >
    <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://example.org" />
  </include>
</static-files>
```

If you're using Python, edit your `app.yaml` file to include something like

```
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

See [Java app configuration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig) of [Python app configuration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig) for more details and how to make it more specific to your configuration.

Comment: adding this header creates a security issue. do not do this. or at least specify hostname instead of "*"

Comment: @mabn Instead of downvoting the answer why didn't you just edit it? Also, this was correct for this specific question. The question was how to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to '*'. I will edit to take into consideration your security note.