# Font-awesome on my own cdn

Tags: angularjs, extjs, font-awesome, cdn, access-control

I have downloaded font-awesome 4.5.0 and put on my own cdn (cachefly). Then as suggested from [font-awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) i used the link to css file like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mycachefly.cachefly.net/external/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

However, i take the following error:

```
Font from origin 'http://wisa.cachefly.net' has been blocked
from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on 
the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is 
therefore not allowed access.
```

What is wrong here?

*ps: i have no .htaccess file. Its a mixed project from extjs and angular*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14308390/4759033

Comment: where should i use that code?

Comment: @Asqan in apache config

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you do not have CORS enabled which allows resources to be loaded from another domain other than your origin. Some services enable CORS by default such as [fontawesomecdn](https://fontawesomecdn.com/).

There is also an explanation at the bottom of this page for enabling CORS on your origin server whether you're using Apache or Nginx.

Apache - place in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Nginx - place in nginx.conf file

```
location ~ \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$ {
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
}
```